# Replace a specific GUI element dynamically

Tags: java, swing, windowbuilder

I am creating a game where each player fills a 3x3 grid and they all have a different state of the grid (a player object has an instance variable as the grid and the grid is made up of many `JPanel`s).

I have a `JList` of players on the left and on the right the grid is displayed. Is there a way to dynamically change the grid when I click on a player's name in the list?

(I tried doing a `for` loop to update the grid every time a player is selected but then if the player updates the grid after he is selected, it gets hacky to update the grid i.e you have to make the list get the focus etc. so I am looking for a clean way)

EDIT: Also, I thought about changing the reference of the object dynamically and update the UI however I have some action events which enforces me to make the variables FINAL. So I am unable to do this way either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not change the grid when the selection changes. You should change the data displayed by the grid (i.e. the data model of the grid). For example, suppose the grid is a panel containing 9 labels, each displaying one element of a `String[][]`. Your `Grid` object should have a `setModel(String[][] data)` which changes the value of each label in the grid.

Each time the player selection changes, you should ask the selected player for its data, and call `setData()` on the grid. If the data of a player can change while being delected, you should also call setData() each time it changes. This can be done by having a `PropertyChangeEvent` triggered by the `Player` when its data changes, and a listener which updates the grid with the new data if the player triggering the event is the selected player.

Comment: I think this will probably require a for loop, right? In that case, wouldn't be less efficient than other methods such "showing" a different player's grid ?

Comment: Don't care about performance before you have a performance problem. Do you know how many iteration you can do in one millisecond? Do you know how many operations are performed each time you change a component in a GUI? I'm pretty sure my solution is more eficient, because it doesn't need showing another component. But it's not important. What's important is to be fast enough.

Answer (score 3):

You can place 9 panels with `CardLayout` and swap proper cards. Or you can remove the old component and add a new one, instead calling `revalidate()` and `repaint()` after adding.

Answer (score 1):

So basically you have a list of players where the selected player determines which grid is shown. If you would use a `CardLayout` for the panel containing the grid, you can ask it to show the grid corresponding to a certain player when the selection gets updated.

No need for special `for`-loops, but just call the `CardLayout#show` method.

A whole [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) is available with information on working with CardLayouts

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve [Concurrency in Swing](http://www.iismarconi.net/inside/materiale/java/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) you must schedule a job for Event dispatching thread, so that whatever changes are happening to the UI can be displayed without any hickups.

Something like this :

```
public static void main(String... args)
{
  // Used to schedule a job for event-dispatcher thread
  SwingUtilites.invokeLater(new RUnnable()
   {
     public void run()
     {
        // put your code for creating and displaying the GUI here.
        // or call the method which is creating and displaying the GUI here.
     }
   }
  );
}
```

So as you make your changes, just use revalidate() and repaint() methods. That will do, what you trying to achieve.
Hope that will be of some help.

Regards